# How to use IEnumerable property of user object in rdlc reports

Tags: c#, rdlc, master-detail

Is any way to use below object:

```
[Serializable]
 public class Product
  {
    public Product() { }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Description> ObjectDescription { get; set; }  

    [Serializable]
     public class Description
      {
         public Description() { }
         public string ProductDescription { get; set; }
      }
 }
```

in rdlc to show list of products with theirs list of descriptions ? Something like:

```
## ProductName ##

## table with Product descriptions ##
```

without subreports and groupint - making report data source as

```
ProductID
ProductName
ProductDescription 1

ProductID
ProductName
ProductDescription 2
```

etc.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry but that not possible, I searched for weeks for a solution to this problem and the only thing I found was this

[Reporting against a domain model](http://codebetter.com/petervanooijen/2009/07/01/reporting-against-a-domain-model/)

I know that is what you **don't** do, but this is the only way. Until now Sql Reporting does not support nested list of object.